# Eclipse Maven Plugin Could not Resolve Repository

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, proxy

I got stuck using Maven Plugin for the whole morning and there are indeed many threads in stackoverflow but I just don't get it, even the accepted answers themselves are hard for me to understand.. Wish someone patient can explain to me what is really going on.

Obviously, there is some connection problem between eclipse and the remote repositories. Many people mentioned that might be the proxy problem but I am not behind any proxy as you can see from the screen shot.

Any idea of how to solve the problem. I am working on a Mac and if any one with a correctly setup eclipse maven can share his settings.xml file under .m2 folder will be gratefully appreciated!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you share your effective pom please?

Comment: @mawia I am not even building any existing project... I just want to create a maven quick start project and it popped the error above. or I am not even in the ballpark per your question.

Comment: is your eclipse able to connect to internet otherwise?

Comment: @mawia I just loaded a screen shot of Eclipse connecting to the m2eclipse repository and it also indicates that the maven has been successfully installed.

Comment: Your eclipse screen shot shows "error condition...operation can not be completed...". Please check if your eclipse is able to access network or not. There is high chance it is not.